# New Zimbra Domain Won't Receive Email

Tags: email, dns, domain, zimbra

We already have 3 domains set up in our zimbra installation. All work fine. These domains were not set up by me, though.

We just got a new domain, set up the MX records just like the other ones. Then we created a domain in zimbra through the admin console, but still can't receive email. What am I doing wrong? Is there a step I'm missing?

I checked MX records for all 3 domains, they match the new domain we're adding.

Is there some kind of a CLI command I need to run?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error message replies when you try to send an email to the new domain?

Comment: Yes. It says `The response from the remote server was: 554 5.1.2 Recipient address rejected: User unknown` I'm sending this from a gmail account and it seems like this message is from gmail. Not from zimbra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a spam filter issue. Our firewall redirects all communication coming to our mail server to an antivirus installation. Antivirus decides what domains are active. We had to add our new domain to our safe list of domains.

Comment: In order to be more help to others experiencing the same/similar issues, could you perhaps expand on the issues? Right now this tells us the problem is solved, but it does not give us an actual solution, so this is not an "answer".

Comment: I think it is an answer. Let me know what part doesn't make sense to you and I'll explain. Our SMG appliance decides what domains are active. If you don't mark a domain as active, you can email it all you want, it won't deliver the email to the inbox.